# Sending data from Dart to PHP using POST method

Tags: html, dart

I am trying to send some data from Dart to PHP...
This is the code i am using to send the data from Dart:

```
button.onClick.listen((e) {
  var req = new HttpRequest();


  req.onReadyStateChange.listen((HttpRequestProgressEvent e) {
    if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE) {
      print('Data submitted!');
    }
  });


  req.open('POST', form.action);
  req.send('hello from dart');

});
```

In my PHP file I am trying to use the string i have send from dart, but count($_POST) returns 0. $_POST seems to be empty...

Dart code DOES trigger the php script and 'Data submitted' is printed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually related to your PHP configuration. You can access the POST'd data with PHP's reserved variable: [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) However the preferred method is to use [php://input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Answer (score 2):

I am very new to Dart, but you can use FormData in the send. So a quick and dirty way could be.

```
    var data_form = new FormData(query('#My_form'));

    button.onClick.listen((e){
           var request = new HttpRequest():
           request.open('POST', 'http://Localhost/form_data.php');
           request.send(data_form);
```